# Problems With Double-Entry with update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set up an update query to add the last entry with the new entry but my new entry keeps doubling.
I keep looking for error but everything seems ok in not sure why the value of sum keeps doubling.

```
$sum ='1';
$sql = "update table set old = old +'$sum' where id='1'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("A ok");</script>';
} else {
    echo "Bigo Problem: " . $con->error;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? old is of what type? if its a date, then you should either update the old value in php usibg strtodate or in MySQL using DATEADD

Comment: o no it is not a date it is not an error what happens is that my new value doubles when i run the code

Comment: try echoing the query instead of running it, to isolate the problem: check whether the php calculation is wrong, and if not, its an SQL issue

Comment: i just echo de query and it prints 1 which is the one from sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This**

```
  $sum =1;
     $sql = "update table set old = old +'$sum' where id=1";

   if ($con->query($sql) == TRUE) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
              alert ("A ok");

            </script>';
   } else {
      echo "Bigo Problem: " . $con->error;
  }
```

This is the reason for doubling sum because query exected twice by your code.

> $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
>
> if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE)

Remove one line and code will work fine.

Comment: the query is incorrect. please double check the quotes.

Comment: the single quote is not required, and incorrect. `$sql = "update table set old = old + {$sum} where id=1";` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

issue with below two lines.

```
     $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
```

Above two line make two entry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` executes your query....and then `$con->query($sql)` also executes your query.

So you are running the same query twice from two different commands.

You can just remove `$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);` - it isn't needed.